# How to create td border with text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to create a simply table with default border and then get the 'hover' event on `td` elements (probably by jquery) which will cause:

a) the top border should be black with empty space in the middle

b) in the middle of the border should be displayed the text from the `p` element from that `td`(text should be positioned between hovered and previous element)

the result should looks like (I mark the hovered element by different color):

[image]

I am not sure but probably it is impossible to do that just by using css, I tried to implement simply example but it doesnt work. The idea was to create a two divs (to imitate the top border) and `p` element. The problem is because the divs are always invisible (should replaces the normal `td` border when element is hovered), I also dont know how to position `p` element as needed.

How could I get the right solution?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tableBodyContent = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    tableBodyContent += '<tr>' +
      '<td><div class="myTopBorder"><div class="myBorder leftBorder"></div><div class="myBorder rightBorder"></div></div><p class="myText" value="' + i + ':00">ok</p>Item ' + i + '</td>' +
      '<td><div class="myTopBorder"><div class="myBorder leftBorder"></div><div class="myBorder rightBorder"></div></div><p class="myText" value="' + i + ':00">ok</p>Item ' + i + '</td>' +
      '<td><div class="myTopBorder"><div class="myBorder leftBorder"></div><div class="myBorder rightBorder"></div></div><p class="myText" value="' + i + ':00">ok</p>Item ' + i + '</td>' +
      '<td><div class="myTopBorder"><div class="myBorder leftBorder"></div><div class="myBorder rightBorder"></div></div><p class="myText" value="' + i + ':00">ok</p>Item ' + i + '</td>' +
      '<td><div class="myTopBorder"><div class="myBorder leftBorder"></div><div class="myBorder rightBorder"></div></div><p class="myText" value="' + i + ':00">ok</p>Item ' + i + '</td>' +
      '</tr>'
  }
  $("#timeTableBody").append(tableBodyContent);
});

$("td").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).find(".myBorder").each(function(index) {
      $(this).show();
    });
  },
  function() {
    $(this).find(".myBorder").each(function(index) {
      $(this).hide();
    });
  }
);
```

```css
table {
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

th,
td {
  width: 45px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.myTopBorder {
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
}

.leftBorder,
.rightBorder {
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  display: none;
}

.leftBorder {
  float: left;
}

.rightBorder {
  float: right;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  border-top: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-left: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-right: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

td:hover {
  border: none;
}

.myText {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Mon</th>
      <th>Tue</th>
      <th>Wed</th>
      <th>Thu</th>
      <th>Fri</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="timeTableBody">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pseudo element and data attribute for the content like below:

```css
table {
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

th,
td {
  width: 45px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  border-top: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-left: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-right: 1px solid lightgrey;
  position: relative;
}

td::before {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: -5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(green, green) center left/20px 1px, linear-gradient(green, green) center right/20px 1px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 0;
}

td:hover {
  border-top: 0;
  background: orange;
}

td:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Mon</th>
      <th>Tue</th>
      <th>Wed</th>
      <th>Thu</th>
      <th>Fri</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="timeTableBody">
    <tr>
      <td data-text="3:00">Item 0</td>
      <td data-text="3:00">Item 0</td>
      <td data-text="3:00">Item 0</td>
      <td data-text="3:00">Item 0</td>
      <td data-text="3:00">Item 0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-text="3:00">Item 0</td>
      <td data-text="3:00">Item 0</td>
      <td data-text="3:00">Item 0</td>
      <td data-text="3:00">Item 0</td>
      <td data-text="3:00">Item 0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-text="3:00">Item 0</td>
      <td data-text="3:00">Item 0</td>
      <td data-text="3:00">Item 0</td>
      <td data-text="3:00">Item 0</td>
      <td data-text="3:00">Item 0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you require can be done using CSS alone. By placing the value to display on hover in a `data` attribute on the `td` you can easily read it out in to the content of a psuedo element using `attr()`. Then you can use a similar technique to create the left and right sides of the border on hover, something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tableBodyContent = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var rowArr = (new Array(5)).fill('<td data-hover="' + i + ':00"><i></i><p class="item">Item ' + i + '</p></td>', 0, 5);
    tableBodyContent += '<tr>' + rowArr.join('') + '</tr>'
  }
  $("#timeTableBody").append(tableBodyContent);
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
}

th,
td {
  width: 45px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
}

td i:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 16px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #000;
  display: none;
}
td i:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 16px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #000;
  display: none;
}

td:before {
  content: attr(data-hover);
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: 18px;
  width: 30px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
} 
td:hover {
  border-top-color: transparent !important;
  background-color: #DEDEDE;
}
td:hover p {
  display: none;
}
td:hover:before,
td:hover i:before,
td:hover i:after {
  display: block;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(1) td {
  border-top-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Mon</th>
      <th>Tue</th>
      <th>Wed</th>
      <th>Thu</th>
      <th>Fri</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="timeTableBody"></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `content: attr(data-value)` like this :

[image: solution]

## Full css & shortest solution :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (let i = 0, $tr; i < 10; i++) {
    $tr = $("<tr></tr>")
      .appendTo("#timeTableBody");
    for (var day = 0; day < 5; day++)
      $("<td></td>")
      .attr("data-value", i + ":00")
      .text("Item " + i)
      .appendTo($tr);
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

th,
td {
  width: 45px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  position: relative;
}

td:hover::after {
  content: attr(data-value);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -8px;
  line-height: 12px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: white;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Mon</th><th>Tue</th><th>Wed</th><th>Thu</th><th>Fri</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="timeTableBody">
  </tbody>
</table>
```